# Issue with line breaks in CSV text files generated by rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, encoding, line-breaks

I generate a CSV text file in Rails like this:

```
CSV.generate(col_sep: ';') do |csv|
  sheet.add_row ['1st line']
  sheet.add_row ['2nd line']
end
```

When I open the text file the two lines are there as expected. Unfortunately this file now should be used by a program that reads the file and I get an error message, that the second line is missing. I have a sample file that looks exactly like the file I generated which works fine but my file can't be read properly. It also has the same encoding. Any suggestions where to look? Anything concerning line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a question that can be answered as asked.  You said that a 3rd party program is having trouble reading a text file generated by Ruby, but provided no information on that error and how you think Ruby is related to this error.

Could you please update your original post with the plaintext version of your CSV file and what program you're trying to open it in?